# Tune performance of Ubuntu 20 for running Nginx inside a docker

Tags: nginx

I have a 1gbps server, and I want to squeeze max performance (RPS) from it.
The setup is an Ubuntu bare metal server, on it, there is a docker with Nginx in it.

Although the server is supposed to support 1gbps, it looks like the actual performance is really lame (900RPS).

First, I checked for maybe a CPU issue, this is my TOP:

```
top - 08:26:56 up 5 days, 22:33,  2 users,  load average: 0.40, 0.27, 0.44
Tasks: 271 total,   1 running, 270 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.6 us,  0.4 sy,  0.0 ni, 98.8 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.2 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :  31986.2 total,  12924.5 free,   3720.9 used,  15340.8 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   1024.0 total,   1004.5 free,     19.5 used.  27610.2 avail Mem
```

As you can see, we are all good there (we utilize too less, not too much of the CPU power available for us).

I want to check Iftop:

```
TX:             cum:    816MB   peak:   36.8Mb                                                                                                                               rates:   17.3Mb  24.2Mb  26.6Mb RX:                     272MB           13.2Mb                                                                                                                                        7.76Mb  7.92Mb  8.90Mb TOTAL:                 1.06GB           47.3Mb                                                                                                                                        25.1Mb  32.2Mb  35.5Mb


TX:             cum:    288MB   peak:   44.9Mb                                                                                                                               rates:   17.0Mb  18.2Mb  25.0Mb
RX:                     118MB           32.2Mb                                                                                                                                        7.27Mb  7.30Mb  11.8Mb
TOTAL:                  406MB           76.0Mb                                                                                                                                        24.3Mb  25.5Mb  36.8Mb
```

It looks like a VERY poor performance.

This is my server HW configuration:

```
Intel Xeon E-2386G(6c/12t), 3.5 GHz/4.7 GHz
32GB ECC 3200MHz
1TB SSD NVMe
```

I run `Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS "Focal Fossa"`.

This is my `/etc/sysctl.conf` file:

```
fs.aio-max-nr = 524288  
fs.file-max = 611160  
kernel.msgmax = 131072  
kernel.msgmnb = 131072  
kernel. panic = 15  
kernel.pid_max = 65536  
kernel.printk = 4 4 1 7  
net.core.default_qdisc = fq  
net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 262144  
net.core.optmem_max = 16777216  
net.core.rmem_max = 16777216  
net.core.somaxconn = 65535  
net.core.wmem_max = 16777216  
net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0  
net.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians = 1  
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 1  
net.ipv4.conf.all.secure_redirects = 0  
net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 0  
net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_redirects = 0  
net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_source_route = 0  
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 1  
net.ipv4.conf.default.secure_redirects = 0  
net.ipv4.conf.default.send_redirects = 0  
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0  
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 1024 65535  
net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control = bbr  
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 10  
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl = 10  
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes = 5  
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 60  
net.ipv4.tcp_low_latency = 1  
net.ipv4.tcp_max_orphans = 10000  
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 65000  
net.ipv4.tcp_max_tw_buckets = 1440000  
net.ipv4.tcp_moderate_rcvbuf = 1  
net.ipv4.tcp_no_metrics_save = 1  
net.ipv4.tcp_notsent_lowat = 16384  
net.ipv4.tcp_rfc1337 = 1  
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 87380 16777216  
net.ipv4.tcp_sack = 0  
net.ipv4.tcp_slow_start_after_idle = 0  
net.ipv4.tcp_synack_retries = 2  
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1  
net.ipv4.tcp_syn_retries = 2  
net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps = 0  
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1  
net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling = 0  
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 65536 16777216  
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1  
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1  
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1  
vm.dirty_background_ratio = 2  
vm.dirty_ratio = 60  
vm.max_map_count = 262144  
vm.overcommit_memory = 1  
vm.swappiness = 1
```

This is my Nginx conf file:

```
worker_processes auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile 100000;

events {
    worker_connections 4000;
    use epoll;
    multi_accept on;
}



http {

        error_log /var/errors/externalNginx.http.error_1 error;
  lua_shared_dict auto_ssl 1m;
  lua_shared_dict auto_ssl_settings 64k;
  resolver 127.0.0.11;

  # Initial setup tasks.
  init_by_lua_block {
    auto_ssl = (require "resty.auto-ssl").new()

    -- Define a function to determine which SNI domains to automatically handle
    -- and register new certificates for. Defaults to not allowing any domains,
    -- so this must be configured.
    auto_ssl:set("allow_domain", function(domain)
      return true
    end)

    auto_ssl:init()
  }

  init_worker_by_lua_block {
    auto_ssl:init_worker()
  }
        limit_req_log_level    warn;
        limit_req_zone         $binary_remote_addr zone=video:10m rate=30r/s;  # rate=10r/m; #11 Change the rate limit to be 30r per second for a spesific adress - didn't make the change, the issue is not here?
    open_file_cache max=200000 inactive=20s;
    open_file_cache_valid 30s;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
    open_file_cache_errors on;
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    reset_timedout_connection on;
    client_body_timeout 5s;
    client_header_timeout 5s;
    send_timeout 2;
    keepalive_timeout 30;
    keepalive_requests 100000;



  # internal server
  # HTTPS cdn api server
  server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name my.server.com;
        error_log /var/errors/my.server.com error;

        # Dynamic handler for issuing or returning certs for SNI domains.
        ssl_certificate_by_lua_block {
        auto_ssl:ssl_certificate()
        }

        ssl_certificate /etc/resty-default-ssl/resty-auto-ssl-fallback-secondery.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/resty-default-ssl/resty-auto-ssl-fallback-secondery.key;


        location /HealthCheck {
                return 200 "Hello world!";
        }

  }


  # HTTP server
  server {
    listen 80;

    location /HealthCheck {
        return 200;
    }

    # Endpoint used for performing domain verification with Let's Encrypt.
    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
      content_by_lua_block {
        auto_ssl:challenge_server()
      }
    }
  }

  # Internal server running on port 8999 for handling certificate tasks.
  server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:8999;

    # Increase the body buffer size, to ensure the internal POSTs can always
    # parse the full POST contents into memory.
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;
    client_max_body_size 128k;

    location / {
      content_by_lua_block {
        auto_ssl:hook_server()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  externalnginx:
    depends_on:
      - cdnnginx
    container_name: externalnginx
    hostname: externalnginx
    image: externalnginx:2.0
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./externalNginx.conf
    restart: unless-stopped
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '2'  # This is 2/12 of my CPUs (actually use much less than this for some reason), test this with 12 as well. not much help
```

All of this made me think, that maybe, this not working well because I run the Nginx inside a docker and the tuning I have made was for a Nginx that normally runs as a process inside the server, not sure what is the difference should be in the configuration to extract maximum RPS, can anyone here help with this?